# Code in reactJS doesn't allow me to show the value on the input

Tags: reactjs

Given the following data structure:

```
const datos = [{
    tipo1: "11",
    tipo2: "12",
    tipo3: "13",
    tipo4: "14",
    tipo5: "15",
    tipo6: "16"},
  { tipo1: "21",
    tipo2: "22",
    tipo3: "23",
    tipo4: "24",
    tipo5: "25",
    tipo6: "26"},];
```

I'm trying to generate dynamically inputs and being able to manipulate the data in each object property with the following code. However, the inputs do not change when typing.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(datos);

  function updateData(state) {
    console.log(state);
    setData((data) => ({ ...data, ...state }));
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        {datos.map(d=>{
          return(<>
          {Object.keys(d).map((key, index) => {
            return (
              <>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name={key}
                  value={d[key]}
                  onChange={(e) => updateData({[key]: e.target.value })}
                />
              </>
              
            );
          })}
        <br/>
        </>);
        })}
      </form>
    </div>);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been several flaws.
First of all, you have been assigning not the values of the data arrays objects, but data objects. So after change it looked like:

```
data = [
  {
    tipo1: 11,
    tipo2: 12,
    ...
  },
  { ... },
  tipo1: 118
]
```

instead of

```
data = [
  {
    tipo1: 118,
    tipo2: 12,
    ...
  },
  { ... },
]
```

Also, you have been cycling through `datos` instead of `data` in the `return`.

The code:

```
const deepCopyData = (d) => d.map((obj) => ({ ...obj }));

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(datos);

  function updateData(index, key, value) {
    const newData = deepCopyData(data);
    newData[index][key] = value;
    setData(newData);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        {data.map((d, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            {Object.keys(d).map((key) => (
              <input
                type="text"
                name={key}
                value={d[key]}
                onChange={(e) => updateData(index, key, e.target.value)}
              />
            ))}
            <br />
          </div>
        ))}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can check it out in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-leftpad-42moqv?file=/src/App.js:298-1024)